# Default constructor for C++ class that has an object of self type

Tags: c++

I'm making a search tree and have therefore made a node class.
The class contains an object of its own class (parent) and this causes me trouble...

**ATTEMPT 1**

```
class Node {    
    public:
        State state;
        string move;
        static Node parent;     //a different node, which is this ones parent
        
        Node(State state = State(), string move = "");         //Constructor, no parent
        Node(State state, string move, static Node parent);    //Constructor, with parent
};
```

How do I initialize the root node, which does not have a parent and never will?

I tried to define the no-parent constructors like this:

```
Node::Node(State state, string move) {
    this->state = state;
    this->move = move;
}
```

But I get the following error when I compile:
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static class Node Node::parent"

I get that it is because I declare a Node without defining its parent, but how do I define an empty parent?

**ATTEMPT 2**

I tried pointing to a parent node instead...

```
class Node {
    public:
        State state;
        string move;
        Node* parent;       //pointer to a different node, which is this ones parent
        
        Node(State state=State(), string move="", Node* parent=NULL);
};
```

This means I can initialize the root node with a NULL pointer and thereby avoiding the LNK2001 error...

But now my parent node keeps changing...

In another part of my program, I'm working with a Node n and I want to create a child of n.
I use the following function:

```
Node Search::getChild(Problem p, Node n, string action) {
    ...
    return Node(State s, string st, &n);
}
```

So the parent is a pointer to n.
But afterwards I change n to a different node and then the pointer of the child points to the new node, not the old one... How do I avoid that?

**CONCLUSION**
I'm pretty confused about the whole thing, so its a bit tricky figuring out what questions to ask :)
But I hope it makes sense to you! Thanks in advance for any help you can provide :)

Comment: Why is `parent` `static`? This means *all* of nodes would have the same parent.

Comment: Issue with `getChild(Problem p, Node n, string action)` is that you take argument by value and not by reference, and so your pointer become dangling.

Comment: Attempt2 is the correct approach, but you have to fix surrounding code.

Comment: Yksisarvinen: And that's not what I want! But when I write "Node parent" I get the error: "Incomplete type not allowed". I read up on it and figured out that an object can't have a non-static object of self type. Therefore I experimented with making it static, but I guess that wasn't the right way to do it :)

Comment: Jarod42: Thanks!